# How can I remove a stud to fit a range hood vent?

Tags: plumbing, venting, hood

Our kitchen contractor screwed up and forgot to move a stud and plumbing in an exterior wall to accommodate a vented range hood. Cabinets and countertops are now installed. The photo shows what is behind that now finished wall (countertop and cabinets installed too) and also shows the center point of the range and the location of where the range hood needs to vent. (We are looking at a 42" range hood with either an 8" or 10" vent.) Local code calls for sistering the stud at full length if it needs to be notched/cut. I don't know how a full stud could be added since the cabinets and countertops are installed.

What other options are there?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Aside: There are downdraft vents for ranges. Not nearly as effective as a hood, but if you can vent down rather than up ... . Use <your favorite search engine> to search for `downdraft range vent`.

Comment: Not answering the question and I'm far from having much plumbing expertise, but are Fernco connections up to code on spaces that will be permanently enclosed?

Comment: Would't the downdraft have to be installed prior to everything else?

Comment: You might be able to sneak something like [this](https://www.broan-nutone.com/en-us/product/rangehoods/rmdd4804) in if you can scrounge a few inches behind a countertop range. One benefit is that the duct does not need to exit on the centerline of the unit. It can go left, right and/or down to someplace clear of plumbing , ... . Unfortunately, they aren't as effective with tall pots or cooking on the front burners/elements. If you have a freestanding range that's a different kettle of cats.

Comment: Welcome. I've removed the rant and legal portions of your question. We're not a discussion forum, so posts need to focus on the task at hand. Please take the [tour].

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, no-hub connectors are legal in some cases, but they may need to be the fully-shielded type. Also, the clamp on the horizontal one is _really_ crooked. That's prone to loosening over time.

Comment: I'm confused about how you were going to run a duct after cabinets were in in the first place. Why wasn't all the prep work done before drywall? How much of the stud are you planning to remove?

Comment: FYI - it looks like you have a window there.   By code you do not have to run a vent.   That being said you can run any kind of vent that you want.

Comment: @DMoore I know that with bathrooms the requirement is "fan or window". Is that really the case for cooktops too? Bathroom concerns (humidity, odors) are pretty generic - not really any specific spot. But cooktops are a very targeted concern, and general ventilation is not nearly as helpful as "right on top of it".

Comment: Tell us the make model of the hood

Comment: @Anne-install a soffit and run the duct through it to where ever there is room.

Comment: We would like to see how this area looks now so we can suggest viable solutions. I’m liking @ojait  idea to run a soffit

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact - yep same for venting ovens... just bought a nice house with huge kitchen... no vent just a window - window must be able to open per code.

Comment: Thanks isherwood for the response. I certainly wouldn't want rubber bits like that connecting my plumbing in inaccessible places, esp. behind installed cabinets. I suppose that's where what's code legal and what's best practice deviate.

Comment: What is the exterior of this wall?

Comment: @Anne  can you remove the piece of plywood and get a photo?

Comment: In looking at your ceiling picture, I have a lot of concern about that wiring, as I see two junction boxes that are likely closed into your ceiling now.  By code (in at least most jurisdictions, if not all) any junction needs to be accessible in some manner, and if these are closed into the ceiling, they are against code to be there.  Maybe the electrician rewired all of that, but I'd question that, at least based on the picture.

Comment: @Anne can you remove the plywood piece and take a photo?

Comment: Fit a Round to rectangular duct transition in the 5” space with round side facing into kitchen  8”round to 5x12 rectangle

Answer (score 1):

Options that avoid moving the range or knocking open the wall:

1. Go for an unvented hood
2. If there's no top cabinets you could get a ducted hood and run the duct inside the kitchen across the wall then outside where possible.  The choice of hood, size of the duct, and number of bends all have to be to code and planned by someone with more knowledge than me but I hope this can give you some direction if you like the idea.  With some thought this could be made to be not too ugly, e.g. an industrial-look duct, or build a plenum around it.

Comment: A note about unvented hoods: I think it's safe to assume these are electric appliances, but worth noting for anyone looking down the road that a gas burning appliance needs some form of exhaust.

Answer (score 1):

Give us a picture of what it looks like now.

Assuming the current hood doesn't allow for the duct configuration required to work with the existing situation, Aside from *possibly* creative (unsightly) ductwork with a range hood UL listed for multiple bends in close proximity to the connection along with likely losing some cabinets if room for the ductwork is needed and ducting through the roof, there are no other safe/code approved solutions with the current stove type. You may need to get a lawyer, start with a demand letter to the contractor. As @HABO notes, you might be able to replace your range with a downdraft unit, but there might be just a many issues below as above...

If it's an electric range in a jurisdiction governed by out of date regulations that don't prescribe any exhaust requirements and a more "libertarian" minded inspector, a certain type of homeowner might just cut through the stud as is as an unpermitted renovation after the fact, careful to move the wire out of the way, as long as the existing permit can be closed without a vent in place, and as long as such a renovation doesn't violate any of the regulations in your jurisdiction including the need for such work to be permitted. A certain type of homeowner might be willing to take the risk that further modifying a single stud that is already rendered structurally irrelevant by a pipe running through it above is an acceptable level of risk, and doing so without the intention of transferring its load "sistering", and that type of homeowner might look at such a stud as really only serving the purpose at this point of fastening media for the siding because if the little section of wood left by the penetraction near the top plate really is the Las thing holding up your house you've got bigger problems.

Comment: There's a joist resting on the double plate directly above the "structurally irrelevant" stud.  The double plate has also been cut right through on *both sides* of this joist.  The compromised stud may not be the last thing holding up the house, but it may be the last thing holding up that joist, unless it isn't and in fact the joist is being supported by the floor above it.   If OP is going to open the walls I hope she will rectify all the horrors therein ... plumbing, carpentry, and electrical too.

Comment: @jay613, it's not the last thing holding up that joist. At this point, the rimboard and exterior sheathing anchoring what's left of that top plate are doing the work of supporting that joist at this point. Like I said, "a certain type of homeowner" would call it good given the state of things, and that is qualified in the context of what *should* be done

Comment: Code, smode. +1 ... "fastening media for the siding" - I'll give you three guesses why the contractor 'forgot' to cut that stud out.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many options that this question is a bit unclear.

#1 - Don't vent.   You have a window.   Already meets code.

#2 - Run a bulkhead go out where you want.

#3 - Buy a kit for your vent to make the top of your vent unit run straight up (bigger).   Use that space to figure it out.

Your question isn't about how to vent.   It is how to vent and it looks nice.   There are tons of custom tops for vents that hide this stuff or you can drywall that part.   I see almost a 5" gap that you could go straight out.   Sorry this just has so many options not really sure what you are looking for.

Also usually 6" is required for a round duct by most inspectors.   But given my point #1 you really have no requirement so you can install a 5" duct.   Or you can get ducts in "code" sizes like the 3.5x10 - just an example I have used I am sure there are a multitude of sizes...   There are lots of options.   You do not need an 8" duct unless you are in a commercial kitchen.

Update:   Given the last round of pictures your question is much different.   It was, what can I do... now it is holy crap this won't work because I have a finished kitchen.   So given how nice your kitchen is finished and the fact that you would be INSANE to disassemble this at this point there is only one solution.

1. I have a local metalworks shop build you a custom vent adapter that will fit this and go out the 5" opening.   They will just need to fit it to the 8" pipe and honestly it shouldn't be a big deal to do.   (labeled #1 below)
2. The only other option is that they trim out the top - create a larger metal box/soffit and go out label #2 below.   This could look great or be an eyesore.   This will probably be costly to do if it looks nice.
3. Don't vent, you have windows right there.
4. Buy a different venting system that allows a smaller output or one that has a larger top so you can go out a bigger area.    The vent should have been hooked up and ran before finishing the wall.  Period.   You cannot be picky about getting exactly what you want now unless you are willing to really open up that wall - might mean losing all of the tile - or at least a big big chunk of it.